# Testing windows phone 7.1 app on windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Now from what I see it is possible to test my app on windows phone 8, however would I need to import the project to vs2012 and would i need to download the sdk8.0 or can i use the sdk that i have (7.1, vs 2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the Windows Phone SDK 8.0 to deploy your app to a Windows Phone 8 device. And the SDK 8.0 only works with Visual Studio 2012 (Pro, Express, ...). Here's more reading on deploying and testing 7.1 apps for version 8: [How to deploy and run a Windows Phone app (About deploying and running apps on a Windows Phone device)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_device).

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 is supported on following platforms:
•Windows 7 (x86 and x64)
•Windows 8 (x86 and x64)
•Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (x64)
•Windows Server 2012 (x64)

Comment: yah i know though i think to install the sdk 8.0 i need windows 8 as an os no?

Comment: this is the error i get when i try installing the sdk: "This Product can only be installed on Windows 8 or later 64-bit Machine"

Comment: @user1270078 yes, you need Windows 8 to install WP 8.0 SDK

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new sdk and follow all the explanation of this link :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207030(v=vs.105).aspx